# What is Dbus eavesdropping

Tags: dbus

I'm new to dbus and trying to write a .conf file. I'm struggling to understand the meaning of eavesdropping (and maybe a few more core concepts of DBUS).
I read the man page [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dbus-daemon-1) carefully and it is written there:

> "Eavesdropping" occurs when an application receives a message that was
>   explicitly addressed to a service the application does not own.
>   Eavesdropping thus only applies to messages that are addressed to
>   services

Later the usage of the eavesdrop key under a policy with allow/deny tags is explained, but I can't seem to understand what does eavesdropping means. Isn't it just a way to bypass a policy? What does it mean "Eavesdropping occurs"? Is it some kind of a state?

Comment: If a sender may transmit a message through a second system (message bus) to deliver it's payload to a receiver, that second system may eavesdrop by allowing third parties to decide what they intercept (filter on) and receive. Eavesdropping in this context appears to discuss the policy of whether and what kind of third party services may be given the message (if any), as it is sent to it's ultimate (narrowly defined list) of receiver(s). For instance, in a development setup, you may use a message logger not allowed in production.

Comment: Thanks Jared! But it is later written: "For <allow>, eavesdrop="true" indicates that the rule matches even when eavesdropping". It seems like eavesdropping is more than the policy discussion, it's some kind of a state. But I still can't understand. Do you have a clue? @JaredFarrish

Comment: That's an override to the policy. I don't know that's a state, more of a meta property of the message.